# ¿Por qué en la terminal me aparece zsh: killed cuando ejecuto python?

Tags: python, zsh

Estoy tratando de descargar unos archivos y durante el proceso se detiene automáticamente dando como resultado zsh: killed. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?[image: Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio Code]

código:

```
import duka.app.app as import_ticks_method
from duka.core.utils import TimeFrame
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(2005,1,1)
end_date = datetime.date(2020,1,1)

Assets = ["EURUSD"]

import_ticks_method(Assets,start_date, end_date, 1, TimeFrame.TICK, ".", True)
```

Comment: Parece ser un proceso bien largo por la imagen. ¿Cuanto dura?

Comment: Dura unas 3 horas, es una descarga de datos.

Comment: Sería mejor importarlo/cargarlo/procesarlo por partes, si se puede.

Comment: Si pero quiero saber el por qué sucede eso y como solucionarlo, ya que si un día no puedo hacerlo por partes, estaría en la misma situación.

Comment: Vale, pero la práctica recomendada en la industria es dividir y procesar por partes. Esto disminuye las exigencias de hardware y facilita el reproceso en caso de caídas o errores.

Comment: Eso está genial. ¿Crees que habrá alguien que sepa qué sucede?